# Starting of Tomcat Failed in Netbeans IDE 7.3

Tags: java, tomcat7, netbeans-7

**Show this Error in Tomcat Logs**

Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future

Error occurred during initialization of VM

Too small initial heap for new size specified

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore "Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future" or just to what it says: replace CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled with CMSClassUnloadingEnabled.

Concerning "Too small initial heap for new size specified" I think you messed with "-Xms" param.

Comment: In my case it was the permGen option, I had the M before the number, instead of after it.